# Got file path instead of ImageIcon JAVA

Tags: java

I need to have JTable
<Flag Image, Country, Capital, Population>
But instead of flag image I got String

src/zad1/data/flags/Flag_of_Australia.png Australia Canberra    25130.0

src/zad1/data/flags/Flag_of_Canada.png Canada Ottawa        37067.0

```
public class CountryTable {
String myFilePath;
public Object[][] rowData = new Object[10][];
public String[] columnNames = {"Flag", "Country", "Capital", "Population"};

public CountryTable(String countriesFileName) {
    readFile();
    myFilePath = countriesFileName;
}

public JTable create() {
    return new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
}

public void readFile() {
    try {
        File myObj = new File("src/zad1/data/countries.txt");
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
        int counter = -1;
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = myReader.nextLine();
            if (counter > -1) {
                Object[] temp_str = data.split(" ");
                rowData[counter] = new Object[]
                        {new ImageIcon("src/zad1/data/flags/Flag_of_Australia.png"),
                        temp_str[0], temp_str[1], Double.valueOf((String) temp_str[2])};
            }
            counter++;
        }
        myReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: afaicr you need a custom ```TableCellRenderer``` - i.e. you can't just drop in an ```ImageIcon``` and have it create a renderer automatically. And better to load your files/images as resources:
[Netbeans](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans)
[Eclipse](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse)